# Keep environment between Popen calls

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have a script and want to do the following things:

1. activate an emscripten version (this is configurable)
2. configure cmake with the emscripten cmake toolchain
3. build the project

For 1. I use

```
from subprocess import Popen

emsdk_path = os.path.join(os.getenv('EMSDK'))
emsdk_bat = os.path.join(emsdk_path, 'emsdk.bat')
Popen('{0} activate latest'.format(emsdk_bat)).communicate()
```

and for 2.

```
  Popen(['emcmake', 'cmake', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G "Ninja" ..'], shell=True).communicate()
```

The first call finishes successfully but the problem is then the next call which is a different `Popen` call forgot everything about emscripten because the environment is reset again.

Is there a way to extract the environment state from one `Popen` call and use it in another?

I am aware of the `env` parameter in `Popen` but the problem is that `emsdk.bat` is updating the environment and I don't see a way how I can bring this back into python.

Another thing I tried was to write the environment to a file in the first process

```
Popen('{0} activate latest && echo %PATH% > env.txt'.format(emsdk_exe), shell=True).communicate()
```

But `env.txt` contains still the old environment.

Comment: Is it possible for you to do a `Popen('{0} activate latest && emcmake cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', ...)`? Or do they have to be individual `Popen` calls?

Comment: That works - it's not ideal but certainly acceptable. Write an answer and I will accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in one popen call using ";" as an argument to separate the commands, if you are using bash.

```
  Popen(['{0} activate latest'.format(emsdk_bat),";",'emcmake', 'cmake', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G "Ninja" ..'], shell=True).communicate()
```

This only works if you don't need both out puts as it will only return the final output, but it will keep the instance for the second command.